# Counting the frequency of differing patterns in a character string

Tags: r, string, dataframe, count, frequency

I currently have a string in R that looks like this:

```
a <- "BMMBMMMMBMMMBMMBBMMM"
```

First, I need to determine the frequency of different patterns of "M" that appear in the string.

In this example it would be:

```
MM = 2
MMM = 2
MMMM = 1
```

Secondly, I then need to designate a numerical value/score for each different pattern.

i.e:

```
MM = 1
MMM = 2
MMMM = 3
```

This would mean that the total value/score of M's in `a` would equal `9`.

If anyone knows any script that would allow me to do this for multiple strings like this in a dataframe that would be great?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
a <- "BMMBMMMMBMMMBMMBBMMM"    
tbl <- table(strsplit(a, "B"), exclude="")
tbl
#     MM  MMM MMMM 
#      2    2    1 

score <- sum(tbl * 1:3)
score
# 9
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `table` function.

```
a_list<-unlist(strsplit(a,"B"))
a_list<-a_list[!a_list==""] #remove cases when 2 B are together
a_list<-table(a_list) 

# MM  MMM MMMM 
#  2    2    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses the `dplyr` package. First, I load the library and define my string.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- "BMMBMMMMBMMMBMMBBMMM"
```

Next, I define a function that counts the occurrences of character `x` in string `y`.

```
char_count <- function(x, y){
  # Get runs of same character
  tmp <- rle(strsplit(y, split = "")[[1]])

  # Count runs of character stored in `x`
  tmp <- data.frame(table(tmp$lengths[tmp$values == x]))

  # Return strings and frequencies
  tmp %>% 
    mutate(String = strrep(x, Var1)) %>% 
    select(String, Freq)
}
```

Then, I run the function.

```
# Run the function
res <- char_count("M", a)

#   String Freq
# 1      M    2
# 2     MM    2
# 3    MMM    1
```

Finally, I define my value vector and calculate the total value of vector `a`.

```
# My value vector
value_vec <- c(M = 1, MM = 2, MMM = 3)

# Total `value` of vector `a`
sum(value_vec * res$Freq)

#[1] 9
```

Answer (score 2):

It it's acceptable to skip the first step you could do:

```
nchar(gsub("(B+M)|(^M)","",a))
# [1] 9
```

Answer (score 1):

First compute all diffrent patterns that appear in your sting :

```
a <- "BMMBMMMMBMMMBMMBBMMM"
chars = unlist(strsplit(a, ""))
pat = c()
for ( i in 1:length(chars)){
for (j in 1:(length(chars) - i+1)){ pat = c(pat, paste(chars[j:(j+i-1)], collapse = ""))}}
pat  =sort(unique(pat))
pat[1:5] : [1] "B"     "BB"    "BBM"   "BBMM"  "BBMMM"
```

Next, count the occurence of each pattern :

`counts = sapply(pat, function(w) length(gregexpr(w, a, fixed = TRUE)[[1]]))`

Finally build a nice dataframe to summary everything up :

```
df =  data.frame(counts = counts, num = 1:length(pat))
head(df, 10)
       counts num
B           6   1
BB          1   2
BBM         1   3
BBMM        1   4
BBMMM       1   5
BM          5   6
BMM         5   7
BMMB        2   8
BMMBB       1   9
BMMBBM      1  10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
str_count(a, "MMMM")
```

gives 1

```
str_count(gsub("MMMM", "", a), "MMM") # now count how many times "MMM" occurs, but first delete the "MMMM"
```

gives 2

```
str_count(gsub("MMM", "", a), "MM") #now count how many times "MM" occurs, but first delete the "MMM"'s
```

gives 2